# Передача данных в DataGrid

Tags: c#, winforms

День добрый. Имитирую регистрацию пользователя. Требуется добавлять в Datagrid логин и пароль нового пользователя после нажатия кнопки.

Код:

```
string newLogin = textBox1.Text;
string newPassword = textBox2.Text;
DataBase d = new DataBase();
d.dataGridView1 // ? какие последующие действия тут могут быть реализованы
```

Также хочу спросить, как потом проверять данные, введенные в textbox уже при авторизации, считывая их с DataGrid.

Comment: DataGridView  - это визуальный элемент интерфейса программы, он "хранит" данные до момента окончания работы программы, программу закрыли - данные потерялись. Как вы хотите сохранять данные программы на диске? В базе данных? Какой? А может просто в файле? Тогда в каком формате?

Comment: да товарищ, я знаю, что DGV не хранит данные. Такие задания уж..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если правильно понял то так можно

```
 class User 
    {
        public string Login { get; set;}
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Вот тут проверка того что ввел
        // к примеру на то что мы что то ввели перед тем как нажать
        var l = textBox1.Text;
        var p = textBox2.Text;
        if (l.Length == 0 || p.Length == 0)
            return;

        var user = new User()
        {
            Login = l,
            Password = p
        };

        dataGridView1.DataSource = new List<User>() { user };

        //Вот тут из DataGrid получаем данные
        var user_data = ((List<User>)dataGridView1.DataSource).First();

        MessageBox.Show( user_data.Login + " " + user_data.Password);
    }
```

Comment: спасибо. Можете подсказать, как проверять через два текстбокса, есть ли эти данные в datagrid?